# Javascript - Double File Dragover Event Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a file drag/drop handler (drag a file into the browser window, to be used for upload).

For some reason when I bind the drag/drop listener to `$("body")` instead of to a `$("div")` in the body the events fire several times in a row, sometimes even non-stop (seemingly looping). What could be causing this?

Here's a trimmed down version of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/WxMwK/9/

```
var over = false;

$("body")
    .on("dragover", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (! over) {
            over = true;
            $("ul").append($("<li/>").text("dragover"));    
        }
    })
    .on("dragleave", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (over) {
            over = false;
            $("ul").append($("<li/>").text("dragleave"));
        }
    })
    .on("drop", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (over) {
            over = false;
            $("ul").append($("<li/>").text("drop"));
        }
    });
```

To test: drag a file into the orange area, you'll see the event firing multiple times in a row.

Comment: Dont understand your example, but may be you should use .stopPropagation() to stop the event buble. It is sometimes the reason for multiple event treatment..

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ preventDefault is jquery's way of doing .stopPropagation().

Comment: preventDefault is preventing the default behaviour of the event (if you are clicking on a link, preventDefault avoid to follow the link). Stop propagation stop the event bubling. There are 2 different thing. If you search the word "propagation" in the api page you wrote, you will not find anything..

Comment: Nothing is supposed to happen (in this script), just handle the in/out of the drag action. When the drag is over the body I want to dim the screen and show a message, and hide it when they drop the file or leave the screen.

Comment: I believe you're correct about the bubbling though. I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The anon is (mostly) correct.  To put it simply: when the mouse moves over the *edge* of an element inside your drop target, you get a `dropenter` for the element *under the cursor* and a `dropleave` for the element that was under the cursor previously.  This happens for absolutely any descendant.

You can't check the element associated with `dragleave`, because if you move the mouse *from* your drop target *onto* a child element, you'll get a `dropenter` for the child and then a `dropleave` for the target!  It's kind of ridiculous and I don't see how this is a useful design at all.

Here's a crappy jQuery-based solution I came up with some time ago.

```
var $drop_target = $(document.body);
var within_enter = false;

$drop_target.bind('dragenter', function(evt) {
    // Default behavior is to deny a drop, so this will allow it
    evt.preventDefault();

    within_enter = true;
    setTimeout(function() { within_enter = false; }, 0);

    // This is the part that makes the drop area light up
    $(this).addClass('js-dropzone');
});
$drop_target.bind('dragover', function(evt) {
    // Same as above
    evt.preventDefault();
});
$drop_target.bind('dragleave', function(evt) {
    if (! within_enter) {
        // And this makes it un-light-up  :)
        $(this).removeClass('js-dropzone');
    }
    within_enter = false;
});

// Handle the actual drop effect
$drop_target.bind('drop', function(evt) {
    // Be sure to reset your state down here
    $(this).removeClass('js-dropzone');
    within_enter = false;

    evt.preventDefault();

    do_whatever(evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
});
```

The trick relies on two facts:

- When you move the mouse from a grandchild into a child, both `dragenter` and `dragleave` will be queued up for the target element—*in that order*.
- The `dragenter` and `dragleave` are queued *together*.

So here's what happens.

- In the `dragenter` event, I set some shared variable to indicate that the drag movement hasn't finished resolving yet.
- I use `setTimeout` with a delay of zero to immediately change that variable back.
- But!  Because the two events are queued at the exact same time, the browser won't run any scheduled functions until *both* events have finished resolving.  So the next thing that happens is `dragleave`'s event handler.
- If `dragleave` sees that it was paired with a `dragenter` on the same target element, that means the mouse *must* have moved from some descendant to some other descendant.  Otherwise, the mouse is actually leaving the target element.
- Then the `setTimeout` finally resolves zero seconds later, setting back the variable before another event can come along.

I can't think of a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a listener on the `BODY` HTMLElement for the `dragover`, `dragleave` and `drop`.

When you continue to drag over the DIV, there is a `dragleave` that is fired because the mouse is no more dragging over the BODY, but over the DIV.

Secondly, as you are not stopping the bubble event on the `DIV` (no listener is set), the dragover fired on the `DIV` is bubling to the `BODY`.

If I resume:

The mouse enter the body (in dragover)

--> **fire drag over (body)**

The mouse enter the DIV in the body

--> **fire drag leave (of BODY)**

--> **fire drag over (of DIV)** --> **event bubling** --> **fire drag over (of BODY)**

There is a similar problem with `mouseover` and `mouseout`, which is fixed by using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

May be you can try the same code using `dragenter` event type. If its not working, you can check if the `event.target` is the `BODY`. This test could help to skip undesired drag event.

Good luck

Comment: you've got it backwards; `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are the events broken in this same manner, and `mouseover` + `mouseout` are the ones that work as you might expect.  alas, there is no `dragout` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var over = false; 

$("body")
.on("dragover", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (! over) {
        over = true;
        $("ul").append($("<li/>").text("dragover"));    
    }
})
.on("dragleave", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (over) {
        over = false;
        $("ul").append($("<li/>").text("dragleave"));
    }
})
.on("drop", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (over) {
        over = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use `stop();` to stop animation buildup